# Webpack: How to reuse entry point file in multiple page application?

Tags: javascript, webpack

For example:

I have two .vue file `a.vue`, `b.vue`,

and I want to generate multiple pages, so I need two entry point file `a.js`, `b.js`

But these two .js file are just different in one statement:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './a.vue' // or import App from '.b.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

How could I reuse the entry point file ?

---

Chinese translation：

例如用vue写，a.vue,b.vue两个文件

多页打包的话就要分别为这两个文件各自写一个入口文件，例如a.js,b.js

但其实这两个入口文件除了引入的vue文件不同，其他都相同

```
import vue from 'vue'
import App from 'a.vue' // 这句不同 import App from 'b.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

那么请问有什么办法可以共用一个入口文件呢？

Comment: this is not an entry point. The entry point is the place where you application starts => your code snippet is an entry point (and, again, a.vue is not). You cannot make dynamic imports, you need to have two snippets like yours

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic imports.

If you have a condition that either loads `a.vue` or `b.vue` you can split them both in chunks. Your entry point will be the same for both.
Than load and initialise the one you need.

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const appPromise = condition ? import('./a.vue') : import('./b.vue');

appPromise.then(({ default: app }) => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(App)
  })
})
```

Something like this.
Webpack will split them automatically and you only load the one you need.